# How to Add IF statement around Shortcodes (Echo'd) in PHP? (Hide / Show Tabs)

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, tabs, conditional-statements

I have inserted a set of tabs to my php wordpress template using the following shortcodes

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[tabs style="boxed"]
            [tab title="1"][some content here][/tab]
            [tab title="2"]' . get_the_excerpt() . '[/tab]
            [/tabs]');  ?>
```

This works fine.

I have created 2 x custom checkbox fields called 'tab_contact_1' and 'tab_contact_2' in a custom post.

I would like to add conditional logic  to the tabs so that if the checkbox is true/checked the tab shows. If not it hides. (This is due to some posts having this content available and some not)

I have similar logic working for other custom fields on the site, but not using tabs and was thinking I can apply the same mindset. I took a go at the code (see below) but the page is not loading. I am doing something wrong but can't figure it out. Was hoping for some guidance.

thanks a lot

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[tabs style="boxed"]
' . if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tab_contact_1', true)) { . '
[tab title="1"][some content here][/tab]
'. } .'
' . if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tab_contact_2', true)) { . '
[tab title="2"]' . get_the_excerpt() . '[/tab]
'. } .'
[/tabs]');  ?>
```

Comment: You will have todo the conditional build of the shortcode above the do_shortcode function, you cant have if statements within concatenated strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good practice is not to `echo` single lines, but to store them in a variable and echo out the finaly code like this:

```
<?php

$result = '';

$result .= '[tabs style="boxed"]';
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tab_contact_1', true ) != 'false' ) {
    $result .= '[tab title="1"][some content here][/tab]';
}
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'tab_contact_2', true ) != 'false' ) {
    $result .= '[tab title="2"]' . get_the_excerpt() . '[/tab]';
}
$result .= '[/tabs]';

echo do_shortcode( $result );

?>
```

Comment: Hi Dainis, awesome thanks for the reply. I have pasted in this code in place of what I have and the page loads, but no tabs at all show up now. I double checked my custom field name and the box was actually checked. Can you see a reason why they would not show?

Comment: Hard to tell from this code, but if no tabs load, that means that `if` statement was probably `false`. Check the values you are submitting, meaning, echo out the values received in `get_post_meta`.

Comment: Hi, the tabs started to work (not sure why I just added 2 more) but the conditional logic does not seem to work. I pasted the code here for u to see http://pastie.org/4270539 I did echo out tab 2 as an example and the result is false. But the tab still displays on the front end. Any thoughts? Thanks for the help

Comment: The syntax is correct. If you get wrong results, then there is something wrong with the data given.

Comment: yeah thanks man, not sure what is going wrong. I am echo'ing out the results of the checkboxes (True false results etc) but even when they are false the tabs remain. I did a test to rename the custom fields in the code to something which did not exist and then the tabs don't show. It is somehow that when the result is false it is not hiding it ...damm nearly there, I can feel it! :(

Comment: aah, well. You are checking for a value, meaning `if` searches for boolean true or false. If you are giving it a string `false` it still is a value. I changed the code that might help.

Comment: YES - you are a legend! that was all too easy for you :) it worked like a treat..really appreciate the quick help